# Oracle query to retrieve distinct and common column value based on another column

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I need to retrieve distinct AHQ-WS1 value FROM STYPE column where SCODE is having both 9531 AND 9569.

Basically common STYPE value of two different SCODE values but also being distinct.

Is it possible with only query or need java code seperately?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: What does a "distinct" value mean in this context? Do you want a row where there is only one row with `SCODE` of `9531` and one row of `9569` (so, if there happened to be 2 rows with `SCODE` of `9531` and 1 row for `9569` then you do not want that `STYPE` returned)? Or do you mean that you want the output aggregated so it only returns a single row that matches both `SCODE`s? Or something else?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your table; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data (do **NOT** post data as images as we can't copy/paste/execute them); your expected output; an explanation of the logic of why you get that expected output from your data.

Comment: This - want the output aggregated so it only returns a single row that matches both SCODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select stype from table
group by stype
having count(distinct case when scode in (9531,9569) then scode else null end) = 2
```

Comment: It worked, very nice. Also would like to know what is the logic behind count = 2. Please elaborate. Is it based on no of query parameters.

Comment: The *CASE* part ensures that only SCODES that are in (9531,9569) are counted and the *distinct* keyword makes the count function return the distinct number of SCODES that were found. Since you want STYPEs that have both SCODES you must use  count(distinct ... ) = 2

Answer (score 1):

If you want there to be at least 1 row with `9531` and at least 1 row with `9569` values for `SCODE` then:

```sql
SELECT stype
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY stype
HAVING COUNT(CASE scode WHEN 9531 THEN 1 END) > 0
AND    COUNT(CASE scode WHEN 9569 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

If you want exactly 1 row of each type then use:

```sql
SELECT stype
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY stype
HAVING COUNT(CASE scode WHEN 9531 THEN 1 END) = 1
AND    COUNT(CASE scode WHEN 9569 THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Comment: This as well worked thanks.